# MySQL Batch alter String fields, e.g.: add "x" to start of usernames column

Tags: mysql, string, alter

I've got a set of usernames, some of which I need to alter in the same way: For example, change:

user-name1 to Xuser-name1

user-abc to Xuser-abc

abcuser to Xabcuser

etc.

What would be the syntax? The closest I've got is:

```
UPDATE Table
ALTER username="x+oldusername" 
WHERE username IN ('username1', 'userabc', 'lastuser');
```

Apologies if this is achingly obvious. I've been looking for just under an hour, I can manage basic MySQL but not to this level. Much appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to concatenate strings in MySQL is with [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), and you [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) a column value, not `ALTER` it:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET username = CONCAT('x', username)
WHERE username IN ('username1', 'userabc', 'lastuser');
```